# how to transform data using aggregate function mongodb

Tags: mongodb

How to transform data base on parent_id within self join ? Is this possible make the result as expected. Please help on this thanks

```
db={
  post: [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("59f9c5629f75813e21a6fe34"),
      "parent_id": "0",
      "name": "main_category",
      "short_desc": "",
      "long_desc": "",
      "slug": "main_category",
      "status": true,
      "createdAt": ISODate("2017-11-01T13:00:18.714Z"),
      "updatedAt": ISODate("2019-02-19T07:31:20.967Z")
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("59f9c5629f75813e21a6fe73"),
      "parent_id": "59f9c5629f75813e21a6fe34",
      "name": "sub_category",
      "short_desc": "",
      "long_desc": "",
      "slug": "sub_category",
      "status": true,
      "createdAt": ISODate("2017-11-01T13:00:18.714Z"),
      "updatedAt": ISODate("2019-02-19T07:31:20.967Z")
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("59f9c5629f75813e21a6fe33"),
      "parent_id": "59f9c5629f75813e21a6fe73",
      "name": "sub_category1",
      "short_desc": "",
      "long_desc": "",
      "slug": "sub_category1",
      "status": true,
      "createdAt": ISODate("2017-11-01T13:00:18.714Z"),
      "updatedAt": ISODate("2019-02-19T07:31:20.967Z")
    }
  ]
}
```

output should like this. If any more category does not belongs to anything it should stay blank

```
[
  {
    mainCategory: 'main_category',
    subCategory1: 'sub_category',
    subCategory2: 'sub_category1',
    subCategory3: '',
    subCategory4: '',
    subCategory5: ''
  }, {
    mainCategory: '{if any}',
    subCategory1: '{if any}',
    subCategory2: '{if any}',
    subCategory3: '',
    subCategory4: '',
    subCategory5: ''
  }
];
```

Any hope to get this stat. ?

Comment: take a look at [$graphLookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/index.html#graphlookup-aggregation)

Comment: Can you please make a mongoplayground that help me ?

Comment: My try is https://mongoplayground.net/p/cVEZH2EFYA8

Comment: That may require a schema change so that `_id` and `parent_id` are the same data type.

Comment: any idea you want me on this how can this be fix ?

Comment: If the application is expecting parent_id to be string, changing that could break things.  Perhaps you could use update or aggregate to add a new field with the parent_id converted to ObjectId so it will match the _id values.

Comment: I did that mongoplayground.net/p/cVEZH2EFYA8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$graphLookup` reads from the collection specified by its `from` argument, not from the documents in the pipeline.

In the pipeline you created to change the datatype, use a [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/index.html#merge-aggregation) stage to update the existing documents:

```
db.post.aggregate([
  {$addFields: {
      parent_oid: {
        $cond: {
          if: {$eq: ["$parent_id","0"]},
          then: "$parent_id",
          else: {$toObjectId: "$parent_id"}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$merge: "post"}
])
```

Then you can use `$graphLookup` to form the lists, and transform them to the shape you need:

```
db.post.aggregate([
  {$match: {parent_id: "0" }},
  {"$graphLookup": {
      "from": "post",
      "startWith": "$_id",
      "connectFromField": "_id",
      "connectToField": "parent_oid",
      "as": "response"
  }},
  {$unwind: "$response"},
  {$group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      main_category: {$first: "$slug"},
      subCategories: {$push: {
                              k: "$response.name",
                              v: "$response.slug"
      }}
    }
  },
  {$replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          {mainCategory: "$main_category"},
          {$arrayToObject: "$subCategories"}
        ]
      }
  }}
])
```

Output from the sample data:

```
[
  {
    "mainCategory": "main_category",
    "sub_category": "sub_category",
    "sub_category1": "sub_category1"
  }
]
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1kP6ovkFuEc)

Comment: Awesome ! but what if I added another new category with parent_id : 0 https://mongoplayground.net/p/gCTn1Lo_OVi

Comment: That aggregation depends on you updating the documents to have the ObjectId form of the parent_id.  As written, it will not return any 'main' categories that do not have any sub-categories, but you can get those in the result by using the `preserverNullAndEmptyArrays` option with the `$unwind` stage, and a `$cond` to only run `$arrayToObject` if the array is not empty.

Comment: I am sorry I am new in mongo, I get that error : https://mongoplayground.net/p/zrIGmAidlKR

Comment: [
  {
    "mainCategory": "main_category",
    "sub_category": "sub_category",
    "sub_category1": "sub_category1"
  },{
    "mainCategory": "main_category",
    "sub_category": "sub_category",
    "sub_category1": "sub_category1"
  }, { "new_category": "new_category" }
]

Comment: A couple tweaks to your conditional, also note that this aggregation assumes you have already updated all of your documents to have a `parent_oid` field that is the ObjectId created from the `parent_id` string.  https://mongoplayground.net/p/7X7ETrWJ-l_

Comment: Genius, master of mongodb, hats off to you. Thank you so much for being help me.